# Mysql Can't use AS in query

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT
employees.emp_id,
employees.emp_name_en,
employees.emp_name_ar,
employees.emp_nike_name,
employees.emp_basic_salary,
employees.emp_aw_food,
employees.emp_aw_car,
employees.emp_aw_mobile,
employees.emp_aw_trans,
employees.emp_aw_housing,

((`settings`.`set_value` * `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) / 100) AS insurance_ratio,
(((((`employees`.`emp_aw_housing` + `employees`.`emp_aw_trans`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_mobile`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_car`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_food`) + `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) - ((`settings`.`set_value` * `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) / 100)  AS net_salary,
  (net_salary / 30 ) AS day_salary
FROM
employees ,
settings
WHERE
settings.set_key =  'insurance_ratio'
```

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'net_salary' in 'field list'

how i can use column  'net_salary'

Comment: You need to give the whole code instead of net salary
((((((`employees`.`emp_aw_housing` + `employees`.`emp_aw_trans`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_mobile`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_car`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_food`) + `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) - ((`settings`.`set_value` * `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) / 100)  / 30) AS day_salary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But what you could do...

```
SELECT tab1.*, (tab1.net_salary / 30 ) AS day_salary 
FROM (SELECT
employees.emp_id,
employees.emp_name_en,
employees.emp_name_ar,
employees.emp_nike_name,
employees.emp_basic_salary,
employees.emp_aw_food,
employees.emp_aw_car,
employees.emp_aw_mobile,
employees.emp_aw_trans,
employees.emp_aw_housing,

((`settings`.`set_value` * `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) / 100) AS insurance_ratio,
(((((`employees`.`emp_aw_housing` + `employees`.`emp_aw_trans`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_mobile`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_car`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_food`) + `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) - ((`settings`.`set_value` * `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) / 100)  AS net_salary
FROM
employees ,
settings
WHERE
settings.set_key =  'insurance_ratio') AS tab1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a well-known pain about extensive calculations columns that need to be reused.

```
select emp_id,emp_name_en,emp_name_ar,emp_nike_name,emp_basic_salary,
emp_aw_food,emp_aw_car,emp_aw_mobile,emp_aw_trans,emp_aw_housing,
(net_salary / 30 ) AS day_salary
FROM
(   SELECT
    employees.emp_id,
    employees.emp_name_en,
    employees.emp_name_ar,
    employees.emp_nike_name,
    employees.emp_basic_salary,
    employees.emp_aw_food,
    employees.emp_aw_car,
    employees.emp_aw_mobile,
    employees.emp_aw_trans,
    employees.emp_aw_housing,

    ((`settings`.`set_value` * `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) / 100) AS insurance_ratio,
    (((((`employees`.`emp_aw_housing` + `employees`.`emp_aw_trans`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_mobile`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_car`) + `employees`.`emp_aw_food`) + `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) - ((`settings`.`set_value` * `employees`.`emp_basic_salary`) / 100)  AS net_salary
    FROM
    employees ,
    settings
    WHERE
    settings.set_key =  'insurance_ratio'
) d;
```